# A non-constant random variable independent with a uniformly distributed r.v.

Tags: probability-theory, independence

Given $([0,1], \mathcal{B},P)$ where $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-field and $P$ is the Lebesgue measure, let $X$ be a random variable such that $X(\omega)=\omega$.

Is there a random variable $Y$ such that $Y$ is independent with $X$, but not constant almost everywhere (w.r.t. $P$)?

Comment: **Yes**, for the question in the title: You can have two independent random variables $U,V$, both not constant a.e., where $U$ has the same distribution as your $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Any other r.v. must be a function of $X$.